# вывети то значение где кликнул человек

Tags: php, ajax

Хочу сделать таблицу сравнения товаров на php для это го хочу записать ид по которым он кликнул и сравнить их потом так вот проблема в то что цикл в скрипте обрабатывает все ид . Или только первое помогите

```html
<?
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users');
$i = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
if(++$i >1) break;
 {
  ?>
<script> 

$(document).ready(function() { 

$( "button" ).click(function() { 

$( "#basket" ).show( "slow" ); 

var ID = '<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'; 

$.ajax({ 
url: "myscript.php", 
data: {id: ID},
type: "POST",
}) 
.done(function( data ) {});

}); 
}); 
</script>
<?
}
?>
```

как сделать если кликнул на val 180 то val 180 
так как сравниваться будут три разных объявления

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script> 
$(window).load(function(){ //говорим скрипту что он сработает когда вся страница загрузится
$('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
$( "#basket" ).show( "slow" ); // показываем как откроется форма
var ID = $(this).data('id'); // берет элемент по которому кликнули
$.ajax({ // сам ajax запрос
url: "myscript.php", // обработчик на php 
data: {id: ID}, // даные которые передатся
type: "POST", // метод
}) 
.done(function( data ) { //отладочный запрос по которому заносятся данные 
console.log(data); // выводим отладочную информацию
}); 
}); 
}) 
</script>
```

```html
и тут заменить , кстати js код снизу под php
<button data-id=".$myrow['id']." id='basket-block' val=".$myrow['id']." class='btn btn-primary btn-lg width'>

                          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'>
                          </span>
                          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'>
                          </span>Сравнить

                    </button>
```

Comment: Подскажите, это ответ или продолжение вопроса?

Comment: да, ответ. А так сейчас думаю переделать его